# Visual Basic IF Statements

Tags: vb.net

I'm having issues with my code. I'm trying to validate user input so is only numeric value and not 0, another condition is that dblFatInGrams can't be greater than dblCaloriesInFood. When I add this statement to my code it's going straight to else statement without executing rest of the code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Const intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat As Integer = 9 '9 calories per gram of fat
        Const dblLowFoodPercent As Double = 0.3       'low fat food are less then 30 %
        Dim dblCaloriesInFood As Double
        Dim dblFatInGrams As Double
        Dim intFatCalories As Integer
        Dim dblTotal As Double

        ' Validating user input and show message in lable box
        If (Double.TryParse(txtFoodCalories.Text, dblLowFoodPercent) And IsNumeric(txtFoodCalories.Text) And dblLowFoodPercent >= 0) Then
            If (Double.TryParse(txtFatGrams.Text, dblLowFoodPercent) And IsNumeric(txtFatGrams.Text) And dblLowFoodPercent >= 0) And dblCaloriesInFood < dblFatInGrams Then
                ' User input
                dblCaloriesInFood = CDbl(txtFoodCalories.Text)
                dblFatInGrams = CDbl(txtFatGrams.Text)

                'Calculate fat 
                intFatCalories = dblFatInGrams * intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat

                ' Calculate and dispaly % of cal. from fat
                dblTotal = intFatCalories / dblCaloriesInFood

                ' Dispaly results
                ' Check if fat percentage is grater or equal to 30% and prints out results
                If dblTotal <= dblLowFoodPercent Then
                    lblUserMessage.Text = "Low fat food"
                    lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("P")
                Else
                    lblUserMessage.Text = "High fat food"
                    lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("P")
                End If
            Else
                lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter a number of fat. Not grater than number of the calories and greater than 0"
            End If
        Else
            lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter the number of calories. Greater than 0 "
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I doubt the compiler will guarantee that the evaluation is left to right.   So the variable dblLowFoodPercent is not filled out by the TryParse before you need it.     Try using "AndAlso"  instead of "and"    that might make it work, but it is not a great solution.  In short call TryParse before you need the value out of TryParse.   I am very interested in how this turns out.

Comment: The issue is both your `Double.TryParse()` statements are operating on `dblLowFoodPercent`. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Check your `TryParse` statements, they are both parsing into the same variable `dblLowFoodPercent`. Also, put the right tag, this is VB.net not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code.

1. It seems `txtFoodCalories.Text` should be preserved in the variable `dblCaloriesInFood` in 1st `If` condition.
2. 2nd if condition was incorrect. It uses a constant `dblLowFoodPercent`. It should be `dblFatInGrams`.
3. Removed the `IsNumeric` as `Double.TryParse` checks it.
4. Removed the user input conversions as `TryParse` is doing it already.

Try below.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Const intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat As Integer = 9 '9 calories per gram of fat
    Const dblLowFoodPercent As Double = 0.3       'low fat food are less then 30 %
    Dim dblCaloriesInFood As Double
    Dim dblFatInGrams As Double
    Dim intFatCalories As Integer
    Dim dblTotal As Double

    ' Validating user input and show message in lable box
    If (Double.TryParse(txtFoodCalories.Text, dblCaloriesInFood) And dblCaloriesInFood >= 0) Then
        If (Double.TryParse(txtFatGrams.Text, dblFatInGrams) And dblFatInGrams >= 0) And dblCaloriesInFood < dblFatInGrams Then

            'Calculate fat 
            intFatCalories = dblFatInGrams * intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat

            ' Calculate and dispaly % of cal. from fat
            dblTotal = intFatCalories / dblCaloriesInFood

            ' Dispaly results
            ' Check if fat percentage is grater or equal to 30% and prints out results
            If dblTotal <= dblLowFoodPercent Then
                lblUserMessage.Text = "Low fat food"
                lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("P")
            Else
                lblUserMessage.Text = "High fat food"
                lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("P")
            End If
        Else
            lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter a number of fat. Not grater than number of the calories and greater than 0"
        End If
    Else
        lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter the number of calories. Greater than 0 "
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I did change the code but it is the same issue. Going straight to Else statement and printing out "Enter a number of fat. Not greater than number...." no percentage output blank label. Also changing dblLowFoodPercent to dblLowFoodPercent causing incorrect calculations.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works better...

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Const intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat As Double = 9.0R     '9 calories per gram of fat
    Const dblLowFoodPercent As Double = 0.3R            'low fat food are less then 30 %

    Dim dblCaloriesInFood As Double = 0R
    Dim dblFatInGrams As Double = 0R

    Dim intFatCalories As Double = 0R
    Dim dblTotal As Double = 0R

    Select Case True
        Case Not Double.TryParse(txtFoodCalories.Text, dblCaloriesInFood), Not dblCaloriesInFood > 0
            lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter the number of calories. Greater than 0"
        Case Not Double.TryParse(txtFatGrams.Text, dblFatInGrams), Not dblFatInGrams > 0, Not dblFatInGrams < dblCaloriesInFood
            lblUserMessage.Text = "Enter a number of fat. Not grater than number of the calories and greater than 0"
        Case Else
            'Calculate fat 
            intFatCalories = dblFatInGrams * intCaloriesPerGramoOfFat

            ' Calculate and dispaly % of cal. from fat
            dblTotal = intFatCalories / dblCaloriesInFood
            lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("P")

            ' Check if fat percentage is grater or equal to 30% and prints out results
            If dblTotal <= dblLowFoodPercent Then
                lblUserMessage.Text = "Low fat food"
            Else
                lblUserMessage.Text = "High fat food"
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot]